# Does ServiceStack has some options like singleton in WCF?

Tags: wcf, mono, servicestack

In WCF, we can create a singleton service so everyone could access to a same instance like a static class.

```
   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class MyService
```

Recently considering use ServiceStack instead, but it looks nothing like WCF, so is it able to do such thing?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you move whatever logic requires the singleton behavior to a plain .NET class rather than a ServiceStack Service subclass? ServiceStack service classes are meant to be pretty lightweight and dependency-free.

Comment: hmm..Sorry I don't understand what it really is :p Is that means ServiceStack closer to ASP/PHP(RESTful) rather than WCF(SOAP)? Thank you :)

Comment: esker is right. ServiceStack is an opinionated framework and you should follow the pattern. If you need a singleton then create and refrence it in your Service.

Comment: oh, get it! Please post your comment as answer so i can mark it :)